# Lazy load a list with a generator, then keep that list in memory

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to create a program that can be instantiated with a list of devices without any context data attached to them. This will get saved under a "private" property of the class. Then, I will iterate through that list, loading context data to each device at the time of accessing the item in the list. After I have iterated through each device, I would like to be able to call upon that full list normally, with all of the relevant context data stored.

I've figured that a generator function could be a decent way to do this, but I'm not sure how to return the entire list at the end. I've got code that roughly looks like this, but the generator function returns itself instead of what I intend to be the default/end value.

```
import requests

class Phone:
    def __init__(self, id, name, type):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._phones_cucm = []
        self._phones = []

    def _gen_phones(self):
        try:
            for id in self._phones_cucm:
                phone = self.get_phone(id)
                self._phones.append(phone)
                yield phone
        except StopIteration:
            return self._phones

    def get_phone(self, id):
        # assume this request returns a dict
        resp = requests.get(f"https://example.com/phone/{id}").json()
        phone = Phone(resp["id"], resp["name"], resp["type"])
        return phone

    def get_phones(self, filter):
        # for purposes of the example, assume this just returns a Python list
        # of strings where the string is an id identifying the phone
        self._phones_cucm = requests.get(
            f"https://example.com/phones?type={filter}"
        ).json()

    @property
    def phones(self):
        yield from self._gen_phones()

def main():
    obj = A()
    obj.get_phones("desk_phone")
    for phone in obj.phones:
        print(phone) # prints name of phone
    print(obj.phones) # prints list of phones


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to just append the items to a list in the caller, then use that list.

Comment: Can you not use `phones = list(obj.phones)` in `main`?